# Where do I put custom phpldapadmin templates on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, templates, ldap

I have a server running Ubuntu 9.10, openLDAP and phpldapadmin. The latter has the ability to use templates to streamline node creation and I want to use a custom template [as described here](http://phpldapadmin.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Templates).

My installation (which was done by apt-get) seems to be located at `/usr/share/phpldapadmin/`, but instead of containing a `templates` subdirectory, it contains a symlink to `/etc/phpldapadmin/templates`. True to form, this directory is locked down. When I break in, I'm greeted with a stark absence of any actual templates, let alone the `example.xml` file I've been instructed to crib from.

Does anybody know where I ought to place my custom templates? (Bonus points if you can tell me where to find `example.xml`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm an idiot. The permissions were all whack, but the templates were in two subdirectories: `creation` and `modification`.

After changing the permissions, it's possible to copy `example.xml` (or any template) and create new ones.

Be sure to set the permissions on the new file correctly though. Oh, and purge the cache!

Comment: Also, the part of the templates docs that says *Don't worry about any other files or subdirectories (like creation or modification)* is a **foul lie**. phpLDAPAdmin, at least 1.2.0.5-2+squeeze1 on Debian 6.0.6, won't read templates in the top level `templates/` directory and silently ignores them.

Comment: Also, use `xmllint` (from `libxml2-utils`) to check your templates if they're stubbornly failing to appear even after you remove the `regexp` element, check file permissions, etc. Eg `xmllint --dtdvalid template.dtd custom_Staff.xml`